# Part of First Letter is being clipped in BasicTextField Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a text field. I want, its width to be exactly equal to its content.
Here is my code:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
        .widthIn(0.dp, 200.dp)) {
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.text.length <= 20) {
                    textFieldValue = it
                    onValueChange(tag.id.orEmpty(), it.text)
                }
            },
            enabled = !tag.isDeleted,
            singleLine = true,
            maxLines = 1,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 13.sp,
                color = if (tag.isDeleted) Contrast_Low.copy(alpha = 0.5f) else Contrast_Higher,
                fontFamily = INTER_FONT,
            ),
            decorationBox = {
                TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                    enabled = !tag.isDeleted,
                    innerTextField = it,
                    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                    singleLine = true,
                    value = textFieldValue.text,
                    visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp, start = 0.dp)
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

Issue:
[image]

"C" can be seen being clipped.
Any solution for this?

Comment: Try remove `width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` from `BasicTextField` modifier, it's working fine for me, first char is not clipped.

Comment: Yes removing `width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` do solve this wired behavior.
But, without `width(IntrinsicSize.Min)`, `BasicTextField` get to its default width, I think which is 280.dp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextMeasurer` to measure size of the text and convert it to dp using `Density.toDp()`. Then you can set BasicTextField's width exactly based on it's content.

I also added extra `4.dp` to width, because `13.sp` is really small font size and it still can look like clipped. However, personally i wouldn't recommend you to use smaller size than min size of the input.

```
//Just some demo tag for this code
val tag = remember { Tag(isDeleted = false) }
val density = LocalDensity.current
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(value = TextFieldValue("")) }
//measurer used to measure text
val measurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
//State holding input width. Now 24dp is default so you can see the input when it's empty
var inputWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(value = 24.dp) }
//We need the style also for measurer, so i put it here
val style = remember(key1 = tag.isDeleted) {
    TextStyle(
        fontSize = 13.sp,
        color = if (tag.isDeleted) Contrast_Low.copy(alpha = 0.5f) else Contrast_Higher,
    )
}

Box(
modifier = Modifier
.size(size = 200.dp)
) {
    BasicTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .width(width = inputWidth)  
            .focusRequester(remember { FocusRequester() })
            .background(color = Color.Red),
        value = textFieldValue,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.text.length <= 20) {
                //Measure the size of the text
                val textResult = measurer.measure(text = it.text, style = style)
                inputWidth = with(density) {
                    //Convert text size to dp
                    textResult.size.width.toDp() + 4.dp
                }
                textFieldValue = it
            }
        },
        enabled = !tag.isDeleted,
        singleLine = true,
        maxLines = 1,
        textStyle = style,
        decorationBox = {
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                enabled = !tag.isDeleted,
                innerTextField = it,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                singleLine = true,
                value = textFieldValue.text,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                    top = 0.dp,
                    bottom = 0.dp,
                    start = 0.dp
                )
            )
        }
    )
}
```